# How can I silently get an access token to retrieve information about currently logged in user from the windows graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to write a desktop application that, on Start-up, retrieves information about the currently logged in user from the Graph API and customises some settings based on those results. I don't want the user to have to type in their login details twice every time they log in so I would like to be able to do this silently. My application has been given admin permissions in Azure AD.

I've tried a few different methods. The first is using client credentials as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?tabs=http this gives me a token but I can't use the token on the /me endpoint as it isn't linked to a particular user. If there was a way I could retrieve the ID of the currently logged in user then this would be fine as I could look them up; but I can't find a way to do this.

The other approach is the delegated flow. However this seems to always require user interaction that I can't find a a way to override, even as an admin.

I have also tried the Web Account Manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-wam but this won't work without UI on some of my test accounts (but does seem to on others?).

Comment: If the user is logged in to your application then you should be able to get their object id (oid) from their token. At least that's how it would work with a web app. Maybe you are coding a desktop app and mean the current windows user?

Comment: IMO a delegated flow is the better solution. It makes it transparent to the users that your app reads their profile (because they have to consent to it) and it won't require an Active Directory admin to give admin consent to your app registration.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride apologies, yes this is a desktop app, it is to configure somebody's outlook email Signature when they log in to windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that is now working for me is the Web Account Manager.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-wam

The reason it wasn't working before is that the test accounts didn't have Windows Hello set up which meant they violated the organisations security policy. The token generated with the method at the link allows querying the Graph /me endpoint as needed.